# How to prevent Wizard next() execution in oncomplete using Primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have this command button in my view, which is

```
        <p:commandButton id="NextButton" class="redbutton default-height" style="float :right" 
                         value="Customer datas" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-e" iconPos="right" 
                         actionListener="#{formController.savePartner()}" 
                         action="#{formController.save}"
                         oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('myWizard').next(); javascript:saved=true" update="@form,:growl">
            <f:param name="performValidation" value="true"/>
        </p:commandButton>
```

I want to prevent the "PF('myWizard').next(); javascript:saved=true" part from execution, if there was validation exception. In the backing bean (here formController), I already added this line and as you can see I also added the IF statement as recommended to the oncomplete part.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
```

This codeline is reached, I checked in debug mode, but the Wizard is still jumping to the next page :( What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Did you debug in the browser and took a look at the args object? Are you sure this property is present and set to false? I know that oncomplete takes 3 arguments like this **oncomplete="handleEditRequest(xhr, status, args)**, are you sure that your args is really the args object you expect?

Comment: No, my question is should this work this way or am I doing it completly wrong? I'm not that expert in JS syntax, espesially that here are two JS methods after the IF in the oncomplete

Comment: If you need to use JS then you should understand it or learn it. JSF is still a web framework, sometimes you need to use JS. I am glad to help but you cannot expect us do the work for you. The if should look like **if(condition) ? doStuff() : doOtherStuff()** if used inline, but it would help you to know if args is really args and the property is present and set, therefore you need to analyse it.

Comment: No problem, I want to learn :) I'm using Chrome, where exactly can I view the parameters and they values?

Comment: Take a look here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/. Here you find all you need.